Can I inject args into a function, access it in deeper call in rust
Can I inject args into a function and then access it in deeper call, without event bus.
I expect it can work as it
struct Status(usize);

fn main() {
  let status = Status(0);
  provide("global_status",status);
  call();
}

fn call() {
  deeper_call();
}

fn deeper_call() {
  let status = inject::<status>("global_status").unwrap();
  assert!(status, 0);
}


I suppose you could use a global, mutable singleton containing a HashMap<&str, Box<dyn Any>> but it seems like a very bad idea to begin with. Just pass parameters as parameters, that way it's obvious what is happening and not obfuscated.

Yes, but don't do this:
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct Status(usize);

// Mutable global state. Not good!
static GLOBAL_STATUS: Mutex<Option<Status>> = Mutex::new(None);

fn main() {
  let status = Status(0);
  *GLOBAL_STATUS.lock().unwrap() = Some(status);
  call();
}

fn call() {
  deeper_call();
}

fn deeper_call() {
  // We have to get at that global state, and handle the
  // multiple failure conditions of being used elsewhere, being
  // poisoned, or not being set
  let Some(Status(status)) = *GLOBAL_STATUS.lock().unwrap() else {
      panic!("Status not set")
  };
  assert_eq!(status, 0);
}

This is painful to write, read, and work with. What you should probably do is pass the settings around through methods:
struct Status(usize);

fn main() {
  let status = Status(0);
  status.call();
}

impl Status {
    fn call(&self) {
      self.deeper_call();
    }
    
    fn deeper_call(&self) {
      assert_eq!(self.0, 0);
    }
}

See how much better that is?
